# Drawing the condensed structure of ethylcyclobutane

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, notation

The IUPAC name for this is *ethylcyclobutane*. I know that the formula is $\ce{C6H12}$.

I have no problems drawing the skeletal structure, but I have a little difficulty drawing the condensed structure. I know this is basic, but I just started learning how to name them.

I tried it below. For $\ce{CHCH2CH3}$, am I right to write it in a straight chain?

[image: ethylcyclobutane]

Comment: You don't  draw condensed structures for rings. Draw the ring like a square and condensed the side chain.

Comment: Related: [What is the meaning of parentheses in a condensed molecular formula?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/26728/7951)

Answer (score 2):

$\ce{CH3CH2CH(CH2)3}$ is the best you can do.

If you want to draw the cycle, then you should make it pendant, drwing a bond from the ring to the ethyl group.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no exact definition, what condensed formula means. One might be able to condense the formula up to the following

[image]

**UPDATE**

- Note that I use nonrecommended parentheses type for repeating unit (see e.g. [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/134877/544)),
- and see [Andselisk](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/41328/andselisk)'s [answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/109181/544) for the graphical bond indicator recommendation (in a different branch of chemistry, though).

Comment: Is it possible to condense it like $\ce{(C4H7)C2H5}$

Comment: @PrittBalagopal, (C₄H₇)C₂H₅ formula is not bad. It is not totally unambiguous, but other compounds it might mean, like "ethylbutene" would have different more appropriate condensed formula.

Answer (score 2):

**TL; DR**: In order to unambiguously denote both branching and cyclicity in a condensed structural formula, a linear formula should include a notation for connectivity, like such:

[image]

---

There is a special notation (external linker, [like in mykhal's answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/73905/41328)) for the bridging atoms with connectivities of three and higher in IUPAC's *Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry* [1, pp. 26–27]:

> IR-2.3.4 **Special bond indicators for line formulae**
>
> The structural symbols 
>   $\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(90deg); font-size: 3em}{\Large ~~~[~~}$
>   and
>   $\require{HTML} \style{display: inline-block; transform: rotate(-90deg); font-size: 3em}{\Large ~~[~~~~}$
>   may be used in line formulae to indicate bonds between non-adjacent atom symbols.
>
> *Examples:*
>
> [image: Examples 1-2]
>
> [image: Examples 3-4]

With this in mind, I'd like to propose the following condensed formula for ethylcyclobutane:

[image]

I used a dirty hack by utilizing a redox macros from the $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$ package [`chemformula`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) without arrows which are supposed to denote electron flow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
    \chemsetup{
        modules = {all},
    }

\begin{document}

\ch{\OX{a,C}H(CH2CH2\OX{b,C}\redox(a,b)H2)CH2CH3}

\end{document}
```

#### References

1. IUPAC “Red Book” Nomenclature of Inorganic Chemistry, 1st ed.; Connelly, N. G., Damhus, T., Hartshorn, R. M., Hutton, A. T., Eds.; *IUPAC Recommendations; Royal Society of Chemistry: Cambridge, UK*, **2005**. ISBN 978-0-85404-438-2.

Comment: Nice catch. Unfortunately no such bond indicators are defined in IUPAC recommendations for organic chemistry. I guess if they were, maybe the slightly confusing parentheses would be optional for such simple cases.