# Are CH₃COOH and HCOOCH₃ same?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

Can I write the formula of Acetic acid as HCOOCH₃ or COOHCH₃ insted of CH₃COOH would they represent the same compound with same covalent bond?

Comment: No, they wouldn't. The rules are so trivial they almost never get explained in the textbooks, but still they are **not** immediately obvious from the formula alone. COOHCH3 makes no sense at all, and HCOOCH3 is a different compound.

Comment: $\ce{CH3COOH}$ is an acid called acetic acid or ethanoic acid. This is the main constituent of vinegar. $\ce{HCOOCH3}$ is a rarely written formula for a volatil liquid called methyl formate, boiling at 31.5°C, which has a not too disagreeable odor and can be synthesized in the lab.

Comment: Partly related: [My answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/62898/101286) to a different question

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate): https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/33135/which-one-is-the-best-notation-for-sodium-acetate/33136?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 6):

$\ce{HCOOCH3}$ would likely be rendered as $\ce{H-C(O)-O-CH3}$, the lone hydrogen atom is atttached to the carbonyl group instead of the methyl group being there -- in other words, methyl formate instead of acetic acid.

I suppose that $\ce{HOCOCH3}$ could be interpreted as having the methyl group and hydroxyl group attached to the carbonyl, but you're better off sticking with the widely used ordering $\ce{CH3COOH}$.